# Page Loading Can't Work

Tags: jquery, html

Bom dia,

Estou tentando fazer um page load animado para minha pagina mas o jquery não está conseguindo esconder a div que contem a animação

HTML

```
   <div class="loading" id="background">
   <div class="home" id="homep">
   <p class="home" id="sphere">CONECTANDO O MUNDO!</p>
   </div>
   </div>
```

JQUERY

```
  $(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ $('.loading').fadeOut() }, 1000);
  });
```

CSS

```
#background {
 background: url('http://payload71.cargocollective.com/1/3/111325/3721041/ico_sphere.gif') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
text-align:center;
}
#sphere{
  color:white;
  font-family:Droid sans;
  font-size:80px;
  position:relitive;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:250px;
  opacity:1.0;
  z-index:10;
  }
```

Meu objetivo é que ele fique uns 5 segundos e depois desapareça sozinho, mas não está dando certo, alguém pode me ajudar?

OBS: É o primeiro page loader que tento montar !

Código 
https://jsfiddle.net/u9L7k74w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

troque

```
 $(window).load(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ $('.loading').fadeOut() }, 1000);
  });
```

por

```
 $(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ $('.loading').fadeOut() }, 1000);
  });
```

caso nao funcione, verifique se voce importou o arquivo do JQuery

```js
  $(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ $('.loading').fadeOut() }, 1000);
  });
```

```css
 #background {
 background: url('http://payload71.cargocollective.com/1/3/111325/3721041/ico_sphere.gif') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
top: 0;
text-align:center;
}
#sphere{
  color:white;
  font-family:Droid sans;
  font-size:80px;
  position:relitive;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:250px;
  opacity:1.0;
  z-index:10;
  }
```

```html
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <div class="loading" id="background">
   <div class="home" id="homep">
   <p class="home" id="sphere">CONECTANDO O MUNDO!</p>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, funcionou na primeira !